Double matching | By date & by Name
Here I want to ask your help to count how many matches there are based on two conditions.
For example there is here an example of what I want :
In the 1° Sheet I want to display the matches based on what I wrote right a little while ago.
1° Sheet
2° Sheet
Honestly I don't know how to proceed...
